Conditional Declaration of Variables
I'm trying to implement a workaround for variable and function overloading in VBA.
Is there a way to conditionally declare the datatype WITHOUT making an Array?
I have the workaround, that only works for arrays:
Public p_Array
Public Sub Initialize(ByVal Row As Integer, ByVal Column As Integer, ByVal DataType As String)

    Select Case DataType
        Case "Integer"
            ReDim p_Array(Row, Column) As Integer
        Case "Single"
            ReDim p_Array(Row, Column) As Single
        Case "Double"
        Case "Long"
        Case "LongLong"
        
    End Select

End Sub

I tried the same Sub with just declaring it as p_Array(0) but this only works when using p_Array(0) and not p_Array
I saw that there are generic types for Visual Basic. That would solve my problem perfectly. But I cant seem to find anything about it in VBA, so I assume it doesn't exist?

OT: why don't you declare everything as variant and then try to convert to the variable type that you need later on the process when you need it?

Are you using Excel?

Yes i use excel. I am trying to avoid Variant as much as possible to save up on memory and to have a "defined" type.

Why would you be running low on memory? Variants do not consume all that much more.
